# Aggregate query in MongoDB using javascript trying to convert UTC string date to Date object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm trying to group datetimes by the hour and I am uploading data from a json file. The datetimes are in UTC format as strings though. How do I convert them to Date objects using javascript in meteor?

```
var data = Subjects.aggregate([{$match: no_null},
                  { $project: 
                    { bin: { $hour: new Date("$metrics."+metric") } 
                  } },
                  {$group: { _id: "$bin", count: {$sum: 1} } } ])
```

Metric is already in UTC format.

Here is one document.

```
{
    "metrics": {
      "ACT_04": 3.733333333, 
      "ACT_05": 14.5, 
      "ACT_02": "1970-01-01T05:02:30Z", 
      "ACT_03": 7.0833333329999997, 
      "ACT_01": "1970-01-01T20:03:00Z"
    }, 
    "subject_id": "M10965219", 
    "name": "sub-M10965219_Act"
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual format of the "string"? And do they appear in the "field" or is it actually par of the "key"? Better to show a document so we know what you actually mean

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added it to my original post.

Comment: I might suggest that upon seeing the data you actually have then instead of even storing as BSON Date you actually store as the "milliseconds since start of day" numerically since all you are interested in is that portion and not the "date" itself. `86400000` fits within  a 32-bit integer which is even half the size of a BSON Date at 64-bits. As noted in the answer the "string" is much longer than that even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  the "string" is in "lexical" ISO Format as in `"2018-05-15T20:59:31.502Z"`, then you "could" get the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) parts:

```
Subjects.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$substr": ["$metrics."+metric,0,10] },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

If you have MongoDB 3.6 available then you "could" use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to actually get that into a BSON date format, but you probably want to similarly truncate that string in a similar way for any date rounding you actually want:

```
Subjects.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": { "$substr": ["$metrics."+metric,0,10] }
      }            
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

MongoDB 4.0 has [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) for a little shorter and does the same BSON Date conversion:

```
Subjects.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$toDate": { "$substr": ["$metrics."+metric,0,10] }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

But the basic fact this if your "string" does not actually look like that and cannot really be broken into parts of the string in a consistent way by supported operators, then you are generally far better off converting the dates stored in your collection(s) to be actual BSON Dates in the first place.

The "recommended" thing to do here is instead to actually run the conversion of the data. The `mongo` shell should be sufficient to run "one-off" conversions:

```
var batch = [];

db.subjects.find().forEach(doc => {

  var fields = Object.keys(doc.metrics).map(k => ({
    ['metrics.'+k]: new Date(doc.metrics[k]),
  })).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{});

  batch.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": doc._id",
      "update": { "$set": fields }
    }
  });

  if ( batch.length > 1000 ) {
     db.subjects.bulkWrite(batch);
     batch = []
  }
})

if ( batch.length > 0 ) {
  db.subjects.bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

That's the basic process. Of course if your "strings" are not in an ISO Format or any suitable for passing to `Date()` for conversion, then you'll actually need to take other measures.

At the very least a BSON Date is is an 8-btye data structure with an "internal" numeric representation, where as the equivalent "string" it at least 24-bytes and even longer with words naming days and months. It makes sense to keep data that is essentially "numeric" in nature in that form when working with a database.

My advice is to convert the data, and possibly on import or if you cannot work that out then at least once loaded to the collection. It's better that trying to work with strings for something they are really not meant to do.

> **Note** [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) is considered deprecated and actually now aliases [`$substrBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/), or you can use [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/) depending on the actual encoding of the data. Older MongoDB releases before 3.2 have the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) expression only.

Comment: Using the { "$substr": ["$metrics."+metric,0,10] } would only assign the date portion but not the time portion, right? However, I need to group by the hour.

Comment: @manwitha Then change the `$subtr` to go to the hour or whatever interval you actually need.  `$substr: ["$metrics."+metric,0,13]` using the `13th` index will go as far as the hour. That's the general lesson, as is that you "should" actually convert to BSON Date. You're question did not ask for a specific time period anyway, but it does not change the method.